# minimum and maximum values of keys - group

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Group by same key, find min and max value. **Keys are ordered.**

```
[{key:1,val:2}
{key:1,val:3}
{key:1,val:4}
{key:2,val:4}
{key:2,val:21}
{key:2,val:22}]
```

to

```
[2,4,1,22]
```

Thing is, the **keys are ordered**. For a real time app, i have an array of 20000. I can loop each item and check its group and act but i feel like i should **not** loop every object. There might be other possible solutions like picking random index and relying on the order for optimized code.

Any efficent way is appriciated. I have come up with few solutions but i have a large dataset to pass to chart, i need to optimize.

Comment: what are the values in the array supposed to represent? if you want min/max I would expect something like `[minKey, maxKey, minVal, maxval]` but it doesn't look like that's what you have

Comment: It groups by key, find min and max values of that 'group' and pushes to an array.

Comment: ok but the max value of the val is 21 and it isn't in your array

Comment: Sorry my bad. Fixed it.

Comment: You should add the solutions you've tried otherwise it looks like you want us to do all the work.

Comment: Hi Andy, you are free to not to answer, thanks tough.

Comment: “*I have come up with few solutions [...] i need to optimize*” - without seeing your solutions, how can we optimise them?

Comment: Actually, what I'm free to do is downvote and flag your answer for being too broad.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a hash table for the grouping and get the min and max value by using a default array and map the new minima and maxima.

```js
var data = [{ key: 1, val: 2 }, { key: 1, val: 3 }, { key: 1, val: 4 }, { key: 2, val: 4 }, { key: 2, val: 21 },{ key: 2, val: 1 }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce(
            (r, { key, val }) =>
                (t => {
                    r[key] = ['min', 'max'].map((m, i) => Math[m](t[i], val));
                    return r;
                })
                (r[key] || [+Infinity, -Infinity]),
            {}
        ))
        .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
    
console.log(result);
```